# Logon fails if two tables are in the dataSet

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports

My report fills two tables. It works on the local server, but when published to another server it gives the following error:

> Unable to connect. Login failed.

When I take off the second table and only use the first table, the report works. How can I resolve this?

```
objDataTable = New Data.DataTable
objDataTable.TableName = "Table"
objDataTable.Columns.Add("pes_nom", GetType(String))

objRow = objDataTable.NewRow
objRow("pes_nom") = objProposta.clsPessoa.pesNom     
objDataTable.Rows.Add(objRow)

objDataSet = New Data.DataSet

objDataSet.Tables.Add(objDataTable)

If objProposta.clsDependente.DtDependentes IsNot Nothing Then
  Dim dtCloned As New Data.DataTable
  dtCloned = objProposta.clsDependente.DtDependentes.Clone()
  dtCloned.Columns(3).DataType = System.Type.GetType("System.String")

  For Each row As Data.DataRow In objProposta.clsDependente.DtDependentes.Rows
    dtCloned.ImportRow(row)
  Next

  dtCloned.TableName = "Dependentes"
  objDataSet.Tables.Add(dtCloned)
End If

Bmgviewer1.PathReport = "RptTermoAdesaoHAP.rpt"
Bmgviewer1.DataSet = objDataSet
Bmgviewer1.DataBind()
```

Comment: You need to login your report first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was insert all data in just one table with multiple rows.

I added the following code:

```
   If objProposta.clsDependente.DtDependentes IsNot Nothing Then
            For Each row As Data.DataRow In objProposta.clsDependente.DtDependentes.Rows

                objRow("dep_nom") = row.Item("dep_nom").ToString()
                objRow("dep_cpf_cgc") = row.Item("dep_cpf_cgc").ToString()

                objDataTable.Rows.Add(objRow)
                objRow = objDataTable.NewRow
            Next
        Else
            objDataTable.Rows.Add(objRow)
        End If
```

And it worked.